# How to live stream from Windows 10 app to Youtube?

Tags: c#, .net, ffmpeg, win-universal-app, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm playing around with the YouTube Live Stream API. That's working fine so far, but the next step is to stream the web cam data to YouTube via RTMP.

In the (excellent) documentation at [Google Dev](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/life-of-a-broadcast), it outlines the Life of a Broadcast. However, all steps are documented in detail, except the step I'm interested in:

> Step 3.2: Start your video
>
> Start transmitting video on your video stream.

I was able to use Open Broadcasting Software to stream to a manually created YouTube Live Event, but I have no idea how to do it from my Windows 10 App. I've looked at the [MediaElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.aspx) class, and was able to capture the web cam preview in my app. But I can only find methods to save as a file.

Also found information about FFMPEG, which should probably be able to do the job, but I cannot find a library / DLL to use FFMPEG in my App.

I just need some guidance where to look next, because now I'm just clueless what to do.

/edit: I came across [MPlatform SDK](http://docs.medialooks.com/Es1i0i/), which sounds exactly what I want, but it costs $5000.... Not for a hobby :(

Comment: ffmpeg (can) have dll's...or were you hoping to call out to the equivalent of the ffmpeg command line?

Comment: You might be able to re ask this on "software recs" site, FWIW.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, as you mentioned, FFmpeg does indeed support streaming (output) over RTMP. I'm not sure what you're trying to stream, since depending on that, the solution will be slightly more or less complex. Two basic cases:

1. if you're trying to stream an existing file or something from your screen, you can simply use ffmpeg as a command-line executable in your c# application.
2. if you're streaming custom bitmap data, it's a little bit more complex and you'll have to manually invoke libavformat/libavcodec.

So, first, get some Windows builds of FFmpeg, e.g. from [zeranoe](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/). If you're going to go route 1, just call ffmpeg.exe in your application and you're done. If you want to go route 2, load the relevant libraries into your project and follow tutorials about [writing files](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.5/output__example_8c-source.html) using libavcodec/libavformat. I can give more details if you tell me what data you want to write. Then, just use either approach to open a rtmp:// output stream, and you should be good to go. (Use h264 as video codec and aac as audio codec, and make sure your build has x264 support, which zeranoe does.)

Comment: Thank you. As I said in my question, I'm trying to stream web cam data.

Spinning up FFMPEG from a Windows Store App is not possible as it just does not allow that. I would need a wrapper that does not start a new process.

Comment: Right, so use (2) then, link in libavformat/libavcodec in your application and stream it from there. See output_example.c and other related libavcodec/libavformat examples to learn how it works.

Comment: Thank you, I'm afraid that is the only solution. I have almost zero experience with C (such a long time ago) and that's just too much for this.

Answer (score 3):

Just like @Ronald and @rogerdpack have stated - ffmpeg is probably your best bet.

Assuming you want to both capture and process the video before publishing it up to YouTube, take a hint from other pro software.

The live streaming application [VMix](http://www.vmixhd.com/) which I am pretty sure is also written in .Net/WPF uses the following approach:

- Captures the video stream using the windows DirectShow library Or any other method they support (They have many source types)
- Processes the video internally using whatever filter they need - But basically they just manipulate frames / audio samples
- Present the result A/V data stream as a virtual DirectShow capture device
- Spin up ffmpeg as **an child windows process** with command line switches pointing it to capture from the virtual device and directing it to publish to whatever RTMP server

If you can get away with just using VMix - Go for it, It's quite cheap for it's basic edition. That's what I did anyway going the same path as you did.

Comment: Thank you, I understand this high level, but I cannot do the last step (start up a child windows process). That's the whole issue. I need a wrapper or something like that which does not runs a new process as that is not allowed in Windows Store Apps.
What I'm trying to build is a Windows 10 Universal App for the YouTube LiveStreaming API, where you can broadcast using the camera in your phone / laptop.

Comment: I see, I missed the store app bit. In that case, you will have to use the .Net bindings from the ffmpeg project or librtmp. That is complex, and I wish I could help more.